Read Excel file without using fileupload control - ASP.NET WEBFORM
I need to process data in file excel and load record in a table. The interface shows only one button and I don't want use FileUpload control
User should click a button and the file selection dialog should appear. By selecting the file and choosing ok the file should be processed.

If you want the file to upload without the user having to hit some submit button on the page, then you want/need to adopt a "ajax" file uploader.
the AsyncFileUpload control in the AjaxToolkit has such an ability. So, right after the user hits "ok" in the file selection dialog, the file will upload, and an event code (code behind) can be specified to run. Keep in mind that this "ajax" file upload means that the page is not going to be posted back, and thus any controls and their values etc. can't be used in that code behind code stub.
I believe that you can also have the AsyncFileUpLoad trigger a post-back for you automatic. (Since you can specify a client-side JavaScript event to run after uploading.
So, while you can never specify the file (or folder) with server code, you can adopt a control that does not require a button click after selecting the file.
Now, the AjaxToolkit is quite a large library to introduce for just this feature, but the AjaxToolkit does have a number of other nice controls such as a popup control, and a nice tab control.
Regardless of what upload control you use?
In all such cases, you have to upload the file, and then your server (code behind) can be used to process the Excel file. You can't in any way have server-side code read or select or use some file on the client computer, since that would be a security risk. Hence, while you visit my cat pictures site, I can't then run code to mess around and steal or upload files without user interaction.
Edit: Follow up example with popup dialog
Ok, so say we have some markup to edit a hotel, and we want the user to upload a picture to the hotel.
So, say some markup like this:
(I'll not post all of the markup, just the important parts).
So, say this:
        <div style="float:left;margin-left:20px" class="iForm">
            <label>Description</label> <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNotes" runat="server" Width="400" TextMode="MultiLine" 
                Height="150px" f="Description" ></asp:TextBox> <br />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" f="Active" Text=" Active" runat="server" TextAlign="Right" />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBalcony" f="Balcony" Text=" Has Balcony" runat="server" TextAlign="Right" />
        </div>

        <div style="float:left;margin-left:60px" >
            <asp:Image ID="iHotel" runat="server"  f="UpLoadFile"
                width="400px" height="300px" CssClass="myshadow"
                />


        </div>

        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        <button id="cmdSave" runat="server" class="btn"
            onclick="mysave();return false;"
            
            >
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-saved"> Save</span> 
        </button>

        <button id="cmdCancel" runat="server" class="btn" style="margin-left:15px"
            onclick="myclose();return false;"
            
            >
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"> Back/Cancel</span>
        </button>

        <button id="cmdDelete" runat="server" class="btn" style="margin-left:15px">
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"> Delete</span>
        </button>


        <button id="cmdUpLoadPic" runat="server" class="btn" style="margin-left:310px"
            onclick="myuploadpop();return false"
            >
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"> UpLoad Picture</span>
        </button>



   </div>

    </div>



        <asp:Button ID="cmdUpLoadPostBack" runat="server" Text="upload done" 
            ClientIDMode="Static" style="display:none"
            OnClick="cmdUpLoadPostBack_Click"/>


    <div id="picupload" style="display:none">

        <ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload ID="AsyncFileUpload1" runat="server" 
            OnClientUploadComplete="uploaddone" />
            
    </div>
        <script>

            function myuploadpop() {

                var myDialog = $("#picupload");
                myDialog.dialog({
                    title: "Select picture for Hotel",
                    modal: true,
                    width: "400px",
                    dialogClass: "dialogWithDropShadow",
                    appendTo: "form",
                    buttons: {
                        Cancel: function () {
                            myDialog.dialog("close")
                        }
                    }
                })
            }

            function uploaddone() {
                $('#cmdUpLoadPostBack').click()
            }

        </script>

So, when the user hits upload a file (picture), then we pop a dialog.
hence this:

So, when the user hits the button, we use a jQuery.UI dialog. (I assume that you have both jQuery, and jQuery.UI installed).
So, when user selects a picture, note how they don't have to hit some submit button, but "just" have to select the file.
Hence this:

So, the user selects a picture, and hits ok - they don't even have to hit a submit button.
Code behind:
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then

        If Session("HotelPK") Is Nothing Then
            Session("HotelPK") = 37  ' for testing

        End If
        Dim HotelPK As Integer = Session("HotelPK")

        Dim rstData As DataTable = MyRst($"SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA WHERE ID = {HotelPK}")
        Call fLoader(EditRecord, rstData.Rows(0))

    End If

End Sub


Protected Sub AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete(sender As Object, e As AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs) Handles AsyncFileUpload1.UploadedComplete

    Dim PK As Integer = Session("HotelPK")

    Dim sFileAndPath = $"~/Content/Hotels/{AsyncFileUpload1.FileName}"
    Dim sFileInternal = Server.MapPath(sFileAndPath)

    AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(sFileInternal)

    Dim strSQL As String =
        "UPDATE tblhotelsA SET UploadFile = @File
        WHERE ID = @ID"

    Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL)
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@File", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = sFileAndPath
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = PK

    MyRstPE(cmdSQL)

End Sub


Protected Sub cmdUpLoadPostBack_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim strSQL As String =
        $"SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA WHERE ID = {Session("HotelPK")}"

    Dim rstHotel As DataTable = MyRst(strSQL)

    Call fLoader(EditRecord, rstHotel.Rows(0))

End Sub

In fact, we could have used a standard FileUpLoad control, but of course that would require we add a submit button to our hidden div (that the jQuery.UI dialog pops up). And note that for most web-based dialogs (jQuery.UI, SweetAlert, and many more), with a post-back, then the dialog will collapse when a post-back occurs, and thus we really don't need code to close the dialog, since the post-back will close it for us.
For the refresh (the hidden button that we click after uploading), then I just called my re-loader routine, but in theory, probably just the picture should be loaded/refreshed.

But I don't want FileUpload textbox in mypage. I want show only button. Clicking it event show fileupload dialog..

see my edit and example. We pop a dialog with the FileUpLoader inside. As noted, in this example, we could have used the standard File upload
